# My only choice when flagging a post is "other" ("in need of moderator intervention")

Tags: support, flags

I wanted to flag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28366447/2307070) as spam, but the only choice was "other":

[image: "in need of moderator intervention"]

Why isn't the usual box with a lot of pertinent choices available here?

Comment: You shouldn't flag answers like this as spam, flag them as not an answer. [*A post should be marked as spam ONLY when it contains an unsolicited advertisement.*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/276063)

Comment: @fhdrsdg You should flag them as offensive/abusive.

Comment: @animuson Flagging as abusive makes sense, but that's not what the FAQ post I linked to says: *"It contains gibberish, such as "fsdguejgkfdlk". Again, flag an answer as 'not an answer'"*

Comment: @fhdrsdg Fixed. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because at the moment you clicked `flag`, the answer was already deleted. It was deleted by Bill the Lizard ♦ when it was 7 minutes old, and you flagged it when it was 14 minutes old. Refresh the page more often. ;-)

The only flag option for deleted answers is "in need of moderator intervention".